# Getting 403 forbidden when generating signed url with PUT request to upload an object to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, request, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to give a temporary access to a service account that has only read permission to upload an mp3 to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

For that, I'm generating a `signedurl` but i can't get it to work.

What I'm doing to generate the URL and upload the file :

```
const config = {
    action: 'write',
    expires: '03-12-2019',
    contentType: 'audio/mpeg'
}

const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: './service-account-key.json'
})

let bucketSubDirectory = storage.bucket(bucketName).file('subdirectory/in/bucket/' + songName)

bucketSubDirectory.getSignedUrl(config, (err, url) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return
    }
    console.log(url)
    // The file is now available to be written to.
    let writeStream = request.put(url, {
       headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'
       }
    })
    writeStream.end('New data');

    writeStream.on('complete', function (resp) {
        console.log(resp.statusCode + " " + resp.statusMessage)

    })

})
```

When I execute the script I get a `403 forbidden` response and when I try to access the generated URL from the browser I get the following :

```
<Error>
<Code>MalformedSecurityHeader</Code>
<Message>Your request has a malformed header.</Message><ParameterName>signature</ParameterName>
<Details>Signature was not base64 encoded</Details>
</Error>
```

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [node.js client library documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#getSignedUrl), the method `getSignedUrl` has a parameter `config` which as a parameter `contentType`:

> **contentType**
>
> > Optional
> >
> > string
> >
> > If you provide this value, the client must provide this HTTP header set to the same value.

So you might need to modify your `PUT` request to include this header with the value `contentType: audio/mpeg`.

Also, if you enter the url in the browser you are not doing a `PUT` request but a `GET` one.

**EDIT:**

Also check that your service account which creates the `signedurl` has the right permissions granted. For the code your are running [you need at least the `roles/storage.objectAdmin` role](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles). To grant it:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding yourProjectID --member yourServiceAccount --role "roles/storage.objectAdmin"
```

Once this is done, users will be able to write to the file with just a `PUT` request to the url.

```
const request = require('request');

let url = 'yourSignedURL'

let writeStream = request.put(url, {
       headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'
       }
    })
    writeStream.end('New data');

    writeStream.on('complete', function (resp) {
        console.log(resp.statusCode + " " + resp.statusMessage)

    })
```

Comment: i actually took my code from the documentation you referenced. I'm already passing the contentType to the `getSignedUrl` method. I edited my post now and i added the contentType to the request too. Still getting `403 forbidden`... am i missing something here ?

Comment: This error is mostly due to your service account permissions. I have updated my answer!

Comment: my service account here is a simulation of the user. I don't intend to give full control or even read permission to my bucket for users, hence the use of signed URL. I did try granting permission and i was able to upload the file to cloud even without using the signed URL.  am i misunderstanding the whole purpose of signed URLs here ? thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You are right, I explain myself loosely. What I tried to meant is that the service account used to generate the signedurl must have the role `roles/storage.objectAdmin` role granted. Once this is done you can pass just the signedurl to the users and they will be able to modify the file as I posted in my answer. I updated my answer again.

Comment: So i'm stuck again.. when the mp3 file is save in the bucket its content-length is 0.. if i understand correctly when the signedurl is created, an empty file will be created in the bucket for you to write in it, and that what `writeStream.end()` is for. Is that right ? That method accepts either a string or buffer.. how can call my mp3 file and pass it in that method ?

Comment: @user007 The signedurl is just a url string that allows whoever has it to perform actions on GCP Cloud Storage without needing a Google Account. It does not create an empty object when created. Please, take a look at [the official documentation regarding this topic](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). I believe your new issue is not related with GCP himself but with how to upload an object using an http request. Please create a new question and I'll try to a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i got it actually to work.. and as always my problem was that i misunderstood how the object is saved to the bucket. All i had to do is to add my object in the body of the put request or pass it to writeStream.on() as a string or a buffer. Thanks again for taking the time to answer